# why not load view when i call a function? codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in codeigniter. 
I call a funtion in controller Articles from the view.

```
<li><a href="index.php/articles/Category/1" ><?php echo $item['CATEGORY'] ?></a></li>
```

The function

```
   function getCategories() {

    $this->db->select('ID_CAT,CATEGORY');
    $this->db->from('CATEGORY');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
    }

 function Category($id_cat) {
    if (!$id_cat) {
        $id_cat = 0;
    }

    $this->load->model('graf/home_model');
    $data = array();
    $data['categories'] = $this->home_model->getCategories();
    $filtro_cat = $id_cat;
    $data['article'] = $this->home_model->getArticles($filtro_cat);
    $this->load->view('graf/articles', $data, TRUE);

   }
```

home_model

```
function getArticles($filtro_cat) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ARTICLES');
    if ($filtro_cat != 0) {
        $this->db->where("ID_CAT=".$filtro_cat);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

When i select the button the url changes to  `http://localhost/Graf/index.php/articles/Category/1` but does not load 
`http://localhost/Graf/index.php/articles/`

Why?

Comment: is method `->getCategories()` declared inside `home_model` class?

Comment: yes, home_model have a getCategories and getArticles.

Comment: try to change the function name as category

Answer (score 2):

When you set third argument of `load->view()` to `true` it returns string value and does not output anything

Try changing:

```
$this->load->view('graf/articles', $data, TRUE);
```

to

```
$this->load->view('graf/articles', $data);
```

Comment: I change by $this->load->view('graf/articles', $data); but the url is the same http://localhost/Graf/index.php/articles/Category/1. No call the index function in the controller.

Comment: it won't call the index function...that's how codeigniter routing works. Read the docs on how controllers and routes work

Comment: i read but i dont know why not load the view, even if i use only $this->load->view('graf/articles') when i call the function Category.

Answer (score 1):

set the routes.php in folder config, add this code;

```
$route['articles/Category/(.*)'] = 'articles/$1';
```

and change the link

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('index.php/articles/'.$item['ID_CAT']); ?>" ><?php echo $item['CATEGORY'] ?></a></li>
```

and change your controller to this

```
$this->load->view('graf/articles', $data);
```

Comment: I apply the changes, but is the same, the url does not load the view